# How to edit the side bar widget in pligg

Tags: pligg

I have installed pligg cms , I can see a side bar widget as 'What is Pligg? '. I would like to delete this , how can I ? I could not see any option in the admin panel .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I am kinda a newbie on Pligg CMS, but I this this one is quite easy.

Modules--->Modify Language---->Sidebar :

PLIGG_Visual_What_Is_Pligg : "You can enter your text here"

PLIGG_Visual_What_Is_Pligg_Text : "You can enter your text here"

So you can just insert your own text or simply remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a file named "about_box.tpl" in /templates/name-of-your-template/ (e.g. /templates/bootstrap/)
similar to this:

```
{************************************
******** About Box Template *********
*************************************}
<!-- about_box.tpl -->
{checkActionsTpl location="tpl_widget_about_start"}
<div class="headline">
    <div class="sectiontitle">{#PLIGG_Visual_What_Is_Pligg#}</div>
</div>
<div id="aboutcontent">
    {#PLIGG_Visual_What_Is_Pligg_Text#}
</div>
{checkActionsTpl location="tpl_widget_about_end"}
<!--/about_box.tpl -->
```

edit that to:

```
{************************************
******** About Box Template *********
*************************************}
<!-- about_box.tpl -->
{checkActionsTpl location="tpl_widget_about_start"}
<div id="aboutcontent">
    {#PLIGG_Visual_What_Is_Pligg_Text#}
</div>
{checkActionsTpl location="tpl_widget_about_end"}
<!--/about_box.tpl -->
```

In case you like to remove about box section totally from your sidebar. Go to temapltes/bootstrap/sidebar.tpl

Your codes might be similar to this:

```
{************************************
****** First Sidebar Template *******
*************************************}
<!-- sidebar.tpl -->
{if $pagename neq "submit"}
    {checkActionsTpl location="tpl_pligg_sidebar2_start"}
    <!-- START SEARCH BOX -->
        {include file=$the_template."/search_box.tpl"}
    <!-- END SEARCH BOX -->
    {checkActionsTpl location="tpl_pligg_sidebar_middle"}
    <!-- START ABOUT BOX -->
        {include file=$the_template."/about_box.tpl"}
    <!-- END ABOUT BOX -->
    {checkActionsTpl location="tpl_pligg_sidebar2_end"}
{/if}
<!--/sidebar.tpl -->
```

edit it to:

```
{************************************
****** First Sidebar Template *******
*************************************}
<!-- sidebar.tpl -->
{if $pagename neq "submit"}
    {checkActionsTpl location="tpl_pligg_sidebar2_start"}
    <!-- START SEARCH BOX -->
        {include file=$the_template."/search_box.tpl"}
    <!-- END SEARCH BOX -->
    {checkActionsTpl location="tpl_pligg_sidebar_middle"}
    {checkActionsTpl location="tpl_pligg_sidebar2_end"}
{/if}
<!--/sidebar.tpl -->
```